# How can I slide over values from specific columns to specific columns within the same dataset?

Tags: loops, pyspark

I have a post-joined datasets where the columns are identical except the right side has new and corrected data and a .TODROP suffix appended at the end of the column's name.

So the dataset looks something like this:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
[
    (1, "Mary", 133, "Pizza", "Mary", 13, "Pizza"),
    (2, "Jimmy", 8, "Hamburger", None, None, None),
    (3, None, None, None, "Carl", 6, "Cake")
],
["guid", "name", "age", "fav_food", "name.TODROP", "age.TODROP", "fav_food.TODROP"]
)
```

[image]

I'm trying to slide over the right side columns to the left side columns if there is value:

```
if df['name.TODROP'].isNotNull():
    df['name'] = df['name.TODROP']

if df['age.TODROP'].isNotNull():
    df['age'] = df['age.TODROP']

if df['fav_food.TODROP'].isNotNull():
    df['fav_food'] = df['fav_food.TODROP']
```

However, the problem is that the brute-force solution will take a lot longer with my real dataset because it has a lot more columns than this example. And I'm also getting this error so it wasn't working out anyway...

> "pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Can't extract value from
> name#1527: need struct type but got string;"

Another attempt where I try to do it in a loop:

```
col_list = []
suffix = ".TODROP"
for x in df.columns:
    if x.endswith(suffix) == False:
        col_list.append(x)

for x in col_list:
    df[x] = df[x + suffix]
```

Same error as above.

Goal:

[image]

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your dot representation of the column name makes confusion for the struct type of column. Be aware that. I have concatenate the column name with backtick and it prevents the misleading column type.

```py
suffix = '.TODROP'
cols1 = list(filter(lambda c: not(c.endswith(suffix)), df.columns))
cols2 = list(filter(lambda c: c.endswith(suffix), df.columns))

for c in cols1[1:]:
    df = df.withColumn(c, f.coalesce(f.col(c), f.col('`' + c + suffix + '`')))

df = df.drop(*cols2)
df.show()

+----+-----+---+---------+
|guid| name|age| fav_food|
+----+-----+---+---------+
|   1| Mary|133|    Pizza|
|   2|Jimmy|  8|Hamburger|
|   3| Carl|  6|     Cake|
+----+-----+---+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the .TODROP was causing problems and your solution worked very well. I didn't know you can coalesce like that, I only used it to slide over values to null cells. Thank you very much.